# Fancybox issue with page anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I have a Fancybox popup, however within this popup, I have a lot of content, and I would like to create a few anchors at the top of this content to 'jump' down to specific parts of the popup page. This works, however the background (the main page behind the Fancybox) appears to jump down whenever the anchor is clicked.

This seems like a Fancybox bug, and I am unable to solve it for some reason. Are there any solutions I can try?

I have created a quick JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6J3wV/9/). If you click the "some link" link, you will see that the anchor works, however the background page also jumps down as well - this is the problem.

***Note:***

This only seems to be a bug in **Chrome**.

**HTML:**

```
<a class="fancyTrigger" href="#TheFancybox"></a>
<hr>
<div id="TheFancybox"></div>

Powered by <a href="http://fancybox.net/" target="_blank">Fancybox</a>

    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    v
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    v
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>

      <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    v
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>

    <p>test</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*  Note that the fancybox css file is loaded under the 
"Add Resources" tab to the left.  Normally you would load it in your <head> */

body {
   background-color: #eef;     
}
#TheFancybox {
    display: none;
    height:70px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

**Script**

```
$("#TheFancybox").html("<p><a href='#test'>some link</a></p><p>dsdsds2dsds</p><p>dsdsdsd1sds</p><p>dsdsdsds3ds</p><p>dsds5dsdsds</p><p>dsdsds5dsds</p><p>dsd22dsdsds</p><p>dsdsdsd2222sds</p><p>dsds111dsdsds</p><p>dsdsdsdsds</p><p>dsdsdsaaaadsds</p><p>dd2d2d3dsdsds</p><p><a name='test'></a></p><p>dsdsdsd 2 da dad a dadsds</p><p>dsdsdsdsds</p>");

$(".fancyTrigger").fancybox();
$(".fancyTrigger").trigger('click');
```

Comment: The problem is not happening on FF

Comment: Ah, interesting. I can't open Firefox here for some reason - crashes my computer. Will do a bit of cross browser testing. It's happening in Chrome though, and unfortunately that is the browser the client is using in my case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your easiest option is to add `autoCenter: true` to your options like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#TheFancybox").html("...");
    $(".fancyTrigger").fancybox({
        autoCenter: true
    }).trigger('click');
}); // ready
```

Also make sure you wrap your custom script inside the `.ready()` method

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zfEdk/)</kbd>

---

**EDIT** : you could also set the helpers `locked` to `true` so the page in the background won't scroll at all

```
$(".fancyTrigger").fancybox({
    autoCenter: true,
    helpers: {
        locked: true
    }
}).trigger('click');
```

See updated <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zfEdk/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Still not quite there, but I think this is as close as I'm going to get with it. Doesn't happen in other browsers, so should be ok. Thanks :)

Comment: Appreciate it, though the background still jumps when the link is clicked (in Chrome). Though it goes back to the top again when the fancybox is closed, so that's acceptable imo :)

Comment: @wickywills Works fine for me in Chrome, what version of Chrome are you using? BTW, are you using the latest version of fancybox (download the latest master from [here](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/archive/master.zip))

Comment: My version of Chrome is 32.0.1700.72m, and yeah, I've tried it with the latest version of Fancybox